# Replicate Netflix login and generate cookie

Tags: javascript, api, cookies, reverse-engineering, netflix

Since there is no official public Netflix API anymore, I'm trying to reverse engineer some things on my own. But I'm kind of stuck at the login.

What I'm doing:

1. GET request on https://www.netflix.com/Login
2. Follow the redirects to end up on something like /Login?locale=en-DE
3. Extract the authURL value (required for the login POST later on)
4. GET request on https://assets.nflxext.com/us/ffe/siteui/logging/clientNotifications.min.20150626.js
5. [Failed] Generate and set the "cL" cookie from the content of that JavaScript
6. POST request on https://www.netflix.com/Login?locale=en-DE using the following body format: `authURL=EXTRACTED_AUTH_URL&email=YOUR_EMAIL&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&RememberMe=on`

I think the login fails, because I was not able to obtain the data for the "cL" cookie. For every request I used the exact same request headers as Internet Explorer did.

So I'm looking for a way to get the data from that JavaScript. Probably using regex? But that JavaScript is so minified and unreadable. :/ Some variables like appId and sessionId are still readable, but all the functions and other things have no names other than a,b,c. I tried to use the debugger to walk through that code, but this is just way to much for my brain.

Here are some additional notes:

- I don't want to login on the Netflix website using my browser.
- I want to login to Netflix programmatically. (That's why I asked this question on Stackoverflow).
- I do not want to write a JavaScript application and I never said I'd want to, in fact I don't even know which programming language I am going to use to implement this.
- I do not want to write a browser.
- I spent multiple hours on logging/reverse engineering the login requests. (I used Fiddler and IE's dev tools.)
- I am not planning to do anything illegal with this, it is just a private project.

Comment: Why don't you just login on the actual site?

Comment: Because I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: What's the advantage of doing it that way?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're trying to achieve so that I can try and assist you. If you still need help?

Comment: I'm trying to log into Netflix programmatically just like some people are logging into Facebook programmatically. I'm sort of writing my own Netflix client or maybe I should call it a tool for Netflix. I created a chat and invited you in case you really think you need to know more.

Comment: Okay, so you may, for example, be creating a script that shows you your new recommendations, without actually needing to access the main site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88618/discussion-between-forivin-and-ajaypayne).

Comment: First of all I answer every question on the chat. Secondly it would be my good right to protect my privacy here, as what I'm up to isn't relevant to the question. How ridiculous would Stackoverflow be if questions like "Hot to iterate over an array?" would require the person to explain what exactly he's up to. I'm just asking how to programmatically log into Netflix. I don't even know what exactly I want to do once that is working. It's just a fun project for my free time.

Comment: Also, the downvote button is not to be used, just because you think the question asker is up to no good. The download button is to be used when the question is bad formatted or doesn't show any research effort etc. And I spent probably more than 4 hours on doing research, debugging and reverse engineering on this.

Comment: sidestep the BS using tampermonkey or greasemonkey instead of reinventing a browser in JS.

Comment: I never said, that I want to rewrite anything in JS! I haven't even decided which language I will use and I certainly do not want to write a browser!

Comment: if the code is so offuscated that you can't understand it - how about using a javascript interpretor to run the piece of javascript that you need?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but what you intend to do here may very well be explained as a violation of the DMCA's anti-circumvention provisions, which might explain a) the downvotes and b) the lack of answers.

Comment: @fvu IMO there's no reason that it would be a violation of the DMCA - it's no different than implementing a web-browser for example. All depends what you do with the data after but that's another story.

Comment: @gregswiss 1201 cares very little about what you do with stuff obtained via circumvention, that's a problem. And as lawyer's logic is often seriously different from the usual boolean logic we're used to I prefer to remain on the safe side in these matters. I was just offering a suggestion as to why this question may have gotten very little usable response.

Comment: My guess is that it would take one whole day to create a new API. It will not violate DCMA as long as he is a paying user.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called Web Scraping / Web Crawling.

You can do it with the WebBrowser component from .NET as gregswiss pointed out, but you can also do it with :

**Python** : Scrapy (The most popular web scraper, Also you'll find lot of tutorials)

**Javascript** : Casper JS (wich relies on Phantom JS a headless web browser)

**Java** : Jaunt (it is my favorite, comes with relevant examples), or write your own web scraper using org.apache.commons.httpclient.

**PHP** : http://www.programminghelp.com/php/basic-web-scraping-regex-php/
http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/

Here is an example for logging in with jaunt :

```
try{
  UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent(); 
  userAgent.visit("http://jaunt-api.com/examples/login.htm");

  userAgent.doc.fillout("Username:", "tom");       //fill out the component labelled 'Username:' with "tom"
  userAgent.doc.fillout("Password:", "secret");    //fill out the component labelled 'Password:' with "secret"
  userAgent.doc.choose(Label.RIGHT, "Remember me");//choose the component right-labelled 'Remember me'.
  userAgent.doc.submit();                          //submit the form
  System.out.println(userAgent.getLocation());     //print the current location (url)
}
catch(JauntException e){
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

You can find more example here : http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm

Comment: But it would be so much cleaner and more efficient if I could simply use an http library like curl for that. I mean all that's keeping me from doing that is a single cookie from what I can tell.

Comment: I decided this creates way too much overhead and doesn't allow me to use certain programming languages that have a lack of such a scraping library..

Comment: Scraping will just be killing lots of time doing reverse engineering. It is better to just use an existing web component (e.g. UIWebView for iOS or similar).

Answer (score 2):

There exist a number of approaches that you can use to get Netflix working. You can make you own API which is not that hard. If you intend to have it for your own purposes that will be overkill, but if you intend to have at least some users it is feasible. The main thing you need to remember is that usually a first call is required (to save/get cookie). After that you can login and later display the content to the user or create you own design from the fetched data. Your relevant options:

- You can create native apps (i.e. Android, iOS, Windows Phone) and use the built in browser components that all mentioned platforms have.
- Create a backend API that process one or more login and share the login with many users (if usage terms allows it). The users can be in a browser or native app.
- Browser only for your private usage (or used by others using their own login).

I use a combination of the first and second option in a project of mine. However, my project is not related to anything close to yours except for that it use cookies, login and API. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the requests in the network tab, replicate them using `postman` or something similar to see if they work from anywhere or if you need to have a `session cookie`, then write a script in your chosen language to handle the posts that you will use.

Without giving us more information, you can't really expect people to be able to help any more than this.

Comment: I already i inspected the requests (obviously) and tried to replicate them. But I couldn't replicate the clientside generated cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET, maybe a simpler approach would be to use a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

Simply point it to http://www.netflix.com. You can then set username/password and simulate a click to the submit button and extract data from your pages using DOM. You won't have to worry about extracting and managing cookie etc. as it's essentially taken care of.

Comment: I've already thought of that, but that would create a ton of unnecessary overhead and may not even work since netflix only runs in browsers that support drm, so on WinXP you'd be completely out of luck. Also, this would limit me to Windows in general.

Comment: true there is some overhead. however doesn't the DRM only kick in when you start streaming? outside of windows there's http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/webbrowser/ - not saying that's great but maybe a workaround... in general I like to get thinks working first and then worry about portability etc. later.